# Laravel 5.5 and nGinx: 404 Not Found on all routes except home

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I created a file other than the `default` to configure my laravel APP. The file name is "`laravel`".

The laravel file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  root /home/user/var/www/laravel-blog/public;

  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked php7.0-fpm log?

I found same problem when using fresh install of Laravel 5.5 and found this on the log:

```
WARNING: [pool www] child 5319 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 312.990977 seconds from start
```

There might be a problem with one of your php extension, disabling newrelic worked for me. You can try to add this on public/index.php to disable newrelic for a single transaction:

```
if (function_exists('newrelic_ignore_transaction')) {
    newrelic_ignore_transaction();
}
```